# Tempus dominus: decoupling the rendered date format from the actual value sent upon form submission

Tags: javascript, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using [Tempus Dominus bootstrap-4](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/) version 5.39.0. I can configure the displayed time format in this way:

```
$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    locale: 'en'
})
```

But this sends to server dates in the format: `'DD/MM/YYYY'` while it consumes dates in format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Is there a way to decouple the value displayed in the form from the one sent to server upon submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to do it out-of-the-box. The only way is tweaking dates format (e.g., with `momentjs`) before submitting data.